# I want to sort the dates in ascending order using ramda.js

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I tried the following code but it doesn't work:

```
const startDate = ["2020-07-17", "2090-09-27", "1920-12-11"]

const pathComponents = R.split('-');
  const sortDate = R.sortBy(R.ascend(pathComponents(R.prop(startDate))));


const sortDate = R.sortBy(R.prop('startDate'));

const sortDate = R.sortBy(R.descend( R.prop('startDate')));
```

Comment: I can make little sense of that.  What does your actual input look like? What should your output look like?

Comment: What was the proper error message? Can you please post the same too or please explain what you expected and what you're getting from thiscode.

Comment: The input comes from an array of objects and i have edited the input format also. The output should be sort in descending order

Comment: The dates above are already in a sortable format. I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sort](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#sort):

```
R.sort((a,b)=>new Date(b) - new Date(a), ["10 june 1859", "12 august 1387", "30 december 1998"]);
```

If you want it in descent just change `new Date(b) - new Date(a)` for `new Date(a) - new Date(b)`

Snippet of the result with javascript vanilla:

```js
console.log(["10 june 1859", "12 august 1387", "30 december 1998"].sort((a,b)=>new Date(b) - new Date(a)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm missing something here.  I don't know if this is all you want to do, or if there is something additional going on:

```js
const startDate = ["2020-07-17", "2090-09-27", "1920-12-11"]

const sortDate = sort (descend (identity), startDate)

console .log (sortDate)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
<script> const {sort, descend, identity} = R                         </script>
```

Dates in that format are already intrinsically sortable; that's part of the point of the format.